# Highchart does not display unicode character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

When a title or name contains a unicode character It will be displayed like that.
I want to display French.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwpES.png

```
{ 
       min: 0,
       max:3000,
       tickAmount: 6,
       tickInterval: 600,
      title: {
         text: 'Température (°C)',
         style: {
            color: '#7CB5EC',
            fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS'
         }
      },
      labels: {
         format: '{value}',
         style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
         }
      },
      opposite: true
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure the data you are passing to highcharts is properly encoded?

Comment: @patrys This is problem with title of axises or name of series. Of course, I write static text not a dynamic data

Comment: Try encoding your javascript source file as UTF-8 and also make sure the HTML document which is loaded by the browser is encoded as UTF-8!

Comment: @Oliver I've configured text file encoding to UTF-8 in my Eclipse but not work.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue e.g. on jsfiddle.net? You could use http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/ as a starting point. I'd still blame text encoding somewhere. Is your XHTML XML declaration explicitely noting UTF-8 as the encoding? I.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`?

Comment: @Oliver I can not reproduce this issue on jsfiddle.net. It don't occur this problem on that. But in my JSP page It was liked that image. I also have encode statement in head of jsp

Comment: Your files are also properly encoded?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I fixed my problem. I used notepad++ re encoding that file. Default Eclipse encode UTF-8 not work properly.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem. I used notepad++ re encoding that file. Default Eclipse encode UTF-8 not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

In high chart when you add a title, try to set the useHTML property to true

```
 title: {
            useHTML: true,
            text: "yourText"
        }
```

it works for me in all browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use meta charset="utf-8"  in your html 's meta tag....simply put in your html header

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: I've already add this code in header of JSP file. But not work

Answer (score 1):

add attribute to dataLabels  useHTML: true

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'red',
        style: {
            color: 'black',
            textShadow: ''
          }
      },
      type: 'pie',
      data: [{
        name: 'a',
        y: 4
      }, {
        name: 'b',
        y: 1
      },{
        name: 'c',
        y: 1
      }],

    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

highcharts fails to generate image if content u provide contains special character "'". The quick fix is to replace the character  "’". I assume "'" in test conflicts with lib validation which may also contain same character.

```
 text=text.replace("'", "’")
```

This solves the issue to generate image (not showing with that character).